# Unity 5 - Cloth Contraints

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying out the new Version of `Unity 3D (5.0.0.4f)` and figure out whats new, whats possible now. My experience with Unity 4 free is also just a little.
Anyway I work with the "new" cloth component and have some general questions to different funkctions. The documentation brought no knowledge to me. So I would be thankful if one of you could explain me the different points in an accessible way.

First question touchs the constraints. When I edit the contraints (of a plane for example), there are two options to activate. What are the differents between `Max Distance` and `Surface penetration`. `max Distance` is clear to me but i don't know what the second option does.

Seceond question: I have an tablecloth positioned over a sphere. In playmode when i move the sphere up and the tablecloth react correctly. But the sphere ist temporaliry visible trough the cloth. Its look like a graphicbug then, but ist there a way to prevent this?

So I hope my questions a clear enough to understand. Thanks a lot for your educational effort.

Comment: This is really more of a [game dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) question than a programming one; I don't see any code here.

Comment: all right I will ask there. Thanks.